# Loading shaders in Android from assets - extra symbols at end?

Tags: java, c++, android-ndk, shader

I try to modify Android Opengles 2.0 example to a NDK example and everything is done except loading shaders. 
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/opengl/opengl-es20.html - original

http://pastebin.com/tjtQdLhi - my loading method of shaders from android assets.
If i harcode shaders into char*, triangle always shows and everything is fine, but then i try to load it from a file, sometimes some junk symbols added at end of my shaders so they don't compile. Symbols just and shader file is random (can be in vertex or fragment or both).

I check every thing, only part of getting a source data from shader file is bugged.

[image: Bad shader data]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Asset buffer or content buffer transfered by JNI might be not NULL terminated, so you need to use 'length' parameter when calling glShaderSource.

Comment: looks like RIGHT answer! will test asap